# Async URL Fetch (Retry if failed without blocking)

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

I'm using async url fetch calls to access information from an external server while doing other processing in the mean time. I want to be able to retry the call or change the url to a backup url if the original async url fetch call failed without returning to the original (main) thread since its busy doing other things. Would the best way of doing this to just spawn a secondary thread that does a synchronized url fetch (I'm guessing for this to work I would have to pause/resume to switch between the two threads since app engine is not multicore)? Or is it better to wait for the main thread to complete everything it's doing before retrying the url fetch operation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using secondary thread that runs synchronous URLFetch would do fine in your use case. Having a non-multicore CPU does not affect the operation of threads from the developer's perspective, since the JVM and/or OS would handle that for you.

A small caveat, since GAE is a sandboxed environment, you need to create threads through Google's API. If you haven't already, you can see a short documentation about how to spawn App Engine threads in [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Sandbox).

Note that the spawned thread has a lifetime limited to that of the original request. (i.e. 60 seconds for a frontend instance request) Another good idea is to use [the request timer](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Request_Timer) on the secondary thread to periodically check the remaining available time before making a second URLFetch call, so you could adjust your timeout limit or have your request terminate gracefully if there is not enough time remaining.

Comment: If the request is taking to long can I just redirect the first request to another request that will try the second url instead (will this reset the 60 second timer?) or is it better to use a backed instance?

Comment: @cowmix: Redirecting request would not reset the timer, it is counted from the time a request is received by your app. If the request takes longer than 60 seconds, consider pushing the Task to the [TaskQueue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview) and have your processing done in the TaskQueue's handler instead. Front end task queue has 10 minutes deadline. If 10 minutes still less than what you need, you can direct the Task in TaskQueue to a Backend instance to have 24 hour deadline.

Comment: But a task queue cannot pass the response to the user right? So would I have to save the task queue response to the datastore and have the user client continually poll the datastore checking for the value?

Comment: @cowmix: That is one way to do it. Another way is to use the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview) to push the response from the server to the client, or use your favorite Push messaging service. In retrospect, the simplest approach might be setting up a backend and have the request processed there, which will automatically give you the benefit of having unlimited deadline for user-facing requests. However, this approach is not scalable, since the single backend would be your bottleneck. Depending on your use case, this might be acceptable.

Comment: Just to be clear if the first servlet does a url fetch and it fails wouldn't doing something like response.sendRedirect("/serlvetThatUsesURL2Instead") reset the 60 second counter since a redirect is a valid response?

Comment: @cowmix: Oh, sorry, that kind of redirect would indeed work. I was in thinking in a MVC controller redirect mindset. The recommended way in App Engine to achieve the same result is by re-scheduling your Task in the TaskQueue when you detect that the request would end soon. But pragmatically, sending a redirect response would also work.